# Prove that $\underline{f}(C-D)=\underline{f}(C)-\underline{f}(D)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Definition** Let $f : A → B$ be a function; if $D$ is any subclass of $B$, the inverse image of $D$ under $f$, which we write $\underline{f}(D)$, is the following subclass of $A$: $$\underline{f}(D)=\{x\in A\mid f(x)\in D\}.$$

Suppose that $f : A → B$ is a function, $C ⊆ B$ and $D ⊆ B$. Prove that $$\underline{f}(C-D)=\underline{f}(C)-\underline{f}(D)$$

what i tried is,
$$\begin{align*}x\in \underline{f}(C-D)&\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in C-D\\ &\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in C\ \wedge\ f(x)\notin D\\ &\Leftrightarrow x\in \underline{f}(C)\ \wedge\ x\notin \underline{f}(D)\\ &\Leftrightarrow x\in \underline{f}(C)-\underline{f}(D).\end{align*}$$
Is right?

Comment: Yes. that's fine. You had to begin by : let $ x\in A$.

Comment: Thanks :). I appreciate.